# WooCommerce - Add free shipping for certain products and when the cart which reaches an amount

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, woocommerce

I run an online store with WooCommerce and sell normal products and books. I want to reach the following:

- If somebody has a cart value of < 50 he should pay for shipping
- If somebody has a cart value of > 50 shipping should be free
- If somebody adds a book to the cart shipping is always free

I try this with the following code:

```
   function custom_free_per_class( $return, $package ) {
        // Setup an array of shipping classes that allow Flat Rate Shipping
        $shippingclass_array = array( 'bookshipping');
        // loop through the cart checking the shipping classes
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $shipping_class = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_shipping_class' );
            if ( isset( $shipping_class[0]->slug ) && in_array( $shipping_class[0]->slug, $shippingclass_array ) ) {
                return true;
                break;
            }//if
        }//foreach
    }//function
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_available', 'custom_free_per_class', 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_when_free_is_available', 10, 2 );
    /**
    * Hide shipping rates when free shipping is available
    *
    * @param array $rates Array of rates found for the package
    * @param array $package The package array/object being shipped
    * @return array of modified rates
    */
    function hide_shipping_when_free_is_available( $rates, $package ) {

    // Only modify rates if free_shipping is present
    if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping'] ) ) {
        // To unset all methods except for free_shipping, do the following
        $free_shipping = $rates['free_shipping'];
        $rates = array();
        $rates['free_shipping'] = $free_shipping;
    }
        return $rates;
    }
```

I set it up in the WooCommerce backend that free shipping should be available after a cart value of 50 has been reached. But however this does not work. The above code works - so free shipping is guaranteed when somebody adds a book, but this seems to hinder the other intention (cart > 50) from working. If I remove the code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_available', 'custom_free_per_class', 10, 2 );
```

the functionality with adding free shipping when 50 is reached works, but surely books are not free anymore.

Des anybody has an idea what is going wrong here?
I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself. The input parameter for the function is not ($return, $package) - it is just ($is_available).